# How do I set multiple unique charts in their own DIVs using an AngularJS directive and Highcharts

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

First, a HUGE thank you to anyone who can help me figure out how to get this working!

I am creating a dashboard which shows several main containers. Inside these containers are smaller ones with HighCharts gauges in them.

Each main container is created using ng-repeat. Ng-repeat calls an angularjs directive each time it loops.

```
<span ng-repeat="crs in Locations"><!-- Loops twice in this exammple -->
    <div ng-receive-stats eventid="eid" locationid="crs.ID"></div>
</span>
```

The directive creates two Highchart gauges using common options.

```
app.directive("ngReceiveStats", function () {

// I am the controller for this directive.
function Controller($scope, $element, $attrs, $interval, eventService, $rootScope, $timeout) {
    //SIMULATION FUNCTIONS (TEMPORARY)
    $scope.receiveSiteHealth = 0;
    var p = $interval(function () {
        $scope.receiveSiteHealth = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    }, 1000);

    $scope.overallHealth = 0;
    var q = $interval(function () {
        $scope.overallHealth = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    }, 1000);

}

// I bind the $scope to the DOM behaviors.
function link($scope, element, attributes, controllers) {
    //Shared Current/Overall Health Options
    var healthChartOptions = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'gauge',
            backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        },
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        pane: [{
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            background: null,
            center: ['50%', '90%'],
            size: 100
        }],
        yAxis: [{
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            minorTickPosition: 'outside',
            tickPosition: 'outside',
            labels: {
                rotation: 'auto',
                distance: 20
            },
            plotBands: [{
                from: 0,
                to: 50,
                color: '#C02316',
                innerRadius: '110%',
                outerRadius: '105%'
            }, {
                from: 50,
                to: 75,
                color: '#ED9C28',
                innerRadius: '110%',
                outerRadius: '105%'
            }, {
                from: 75,
                to: 100,
                color: '#47A447',
                innerRadius: '110%',
                outerRadius: '105%'
            }],
            pane: 0,
            title: {
                text: '<div class="text-center" style="font-size:22px;margin-bottom:5px;">0</div>',
                useHTML: true,
                y: 0
            }
        }],
        plotOptions: {
            gauge: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                dial: {
                    radius: '100%'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [$scope.currentHealth],
            yAxis: 0
        }]
    };

    //Customize Current Health Options
    var containerA = $('<div style="width:170px; height: 105px;"><img src="/app/content/img/loadingA_32.gif" alt="loading..." /></div>').appendTo('#currentHealth');
    var optsA = healthChartOptions;
    optsA.chart.renderTo = containerA[0];
    var currentHealthChart = new Highcharts.Chart(optsA);

    //Customize Overall Health Options
    var containerB = $('<div style="width:170px; height: 105px;"><img src="/app/content/img/loadingA_32.gif" alt="loading..." /></div>').appendTo('#overallHealth');
    var optsB = healthChartOptions;
    optsB.chart.renderTo = containerB[0];
    var overAllHealthChart = new Highcharts.Chart(optsB);

    //Watch Current Health
    $scope.$watch("receiveSiteHealth", function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal != oldVal) {
            var chartVal = [parseInt(newVal)];
            currentHealthChart.series[0].setData(chartVal, true);
            currentHealthChart.yAxis[0].setTitle({
                text: '<div class="text-center"><div style="font-size:22px;margin-bottom:10px;">' + newVal + '</div><div style="font-size:11px;">Current Health</div>'
            })
        }
    });

    //Watch Overall Health
    $scope.$watch("overallHealth", function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal != oldVal) {
            var chartVal = [parseInt(newVal)];
            overAllHealthChart.series[0].setData(chartVal, true);
            overAllHealthChart.yAxis[0].setTitle({
                text: '<div class="text-center"><div style="font-size:22px;margin-bottom:10px;">' + newVal + '</div><div style="font-size:11px;">Overall Health</div>'
            })
        }
    });
}

// Return the directive confirugation.
return ({
    controller: Controller,
    link: link,
    restrict: "EA",
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: '/app/directives/templates/receiveLocationStats.html',
    scope: {
        eventid: '=',
        locationid: '='
    }
});
```

});

I am replacing the directive element (shown in the ng-repeat loop above):

```
<div ng-receive-stats eventid="eid" locationid="crs.ID"></div>
```

with HTML found in the templateURL. This creates the main container.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> {{locationid}} - Location Name <a href="" class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a></h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6" id="currentHealth">

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6" id="overallHealth">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-8">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

When the code fires, it does indeed draw out the Highchart gauges. The problem I have is that the gauges (in their unique containers) are all being bunched up into the top main container.

My question is, how can I define a unique main container to place the charts into. I can get them into their own unique containers as per HighCharts docs but I can't seem get them into their own unique main (or parent) container.

Again, thank you to anyone who can help me figure this one out.

A THOUGHT:

In the container declaration:

```
var containerA = $('<div style="width:170px; height: 105px;"><img src="/app/content/img/loadingA_32.gif" alt="loading..." /></div>').appendTo('#currentHealth');
```

where the appendTo() function is. That #currentHealth selector is created and referenced each time the ng-repeat iterates. I know the ID should be unique and my gut tells me it would solve my problem. I've tried several methods to make it work to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because you use the same object `healthChartOptions` as an `optsA` and `optsB`.

When you change the `chart.renderTo` of the `optsB`, it will also affect `optsA` since they point to the same object.

You could use the `angular.copy()` (or any alternative from other libraries) to clone the option object.

```
var optsB = angular.copy(healthChartOptions);
```

Or put the declaration of `healthChartOptions` in a factory function like this:

```
function createChartOptions() {
  var healthChartOptions = { ... };
  return healthChartOptions;
}
```

then use it to create separate options for `optsA` and `optsB`:

```
var optsA = createChartOptions();
...
var optsB = createChartOptions();
...
```

**EDIT:** As mentioned in comments, the problem actually not about the direct container of each chart, but an outer container.

You create a new container for each chart and append it to `#currentHealth` and `#overallHealth` in the template.

The problem is that you have several main containers which have exactly the same template, so there should be several elements that have the same ID `#currentHealth` and `#overallHealth`.

When you append anything to the `#currentHealth`, it will only append to the first element that matched. To avoid this problem, you have to use className instead of ID for those containers.

Change that part of the template to something like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 currentHealth">

</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 overallHealth">

</div>
```

and in link function:

```
var outerContainerA = element.find('.currentHealth');
var containerA = $('<div style="width:170px; height: 105px;"><img src="/app/content/img/loadingA_32.gif" alt="loading..." /></div>').appendTo(outerContainerA);

var outerContainerB = element.find('.overallHealth');
var containerB = $('<div style="width:170px; height: 105px;"><img src="/app/content/img/loadingA_32.gif" alt="loading..." /></div>').appendTo(outerContainerB);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, the solution didn't work. Well it did. It was an alternate way of doing what I'm already doing. The charts showed up just like they did before the code change. The issue here isn't the charts. They render fine. The problem is putting them in the correct parent container. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I see, I think I get it now what you mean by `their own unique main (or parent) container.`, will update the answer to reflect that.